# Index list of arrays keeping dimensionality in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a list of arryas:

```
data = [array([4,2,3,4], dtype=uint16),
        array([6.6, 7.4, 5.0, 9.5], dtype=float32)]
```

I'd like to get the values from the above list of arrays that fulfill a condition, for instance:

```
condition = array([True, False, False, True])
```

In such a way that the result is the following:

```
data[:][condition]
 # Equals to -> [array([4,4], dtype=uint16), 
 #               array([6.6, 9.5], dtype=float32)]
```

Keeping the same shape, obviously it will be reduced in the number of values

I know that doing:

```
data[0][np.where(condition)]
```

It gives me what I want but only for that [0] array.

How can I do it for multiple arrays like these?

Comment: Would `np.array(data)[:,condition]` work?

Comment: What is that `data[:]` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @QuangHoang answer did what I wanted.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to keep the two different dtypes, or make it all float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your arrays in the list are of the same shape, the most elegant way would be to convert your list to numpy array and leverage numpy indexing as @Quang mentioned in the comments:

```
data = [np.array([4,2,3,4], dtype=np.uint16),
        np.array([6.6, 7.4, 5.0, 9.5], dtype=np.float32)] 

condition = np.array([True, False, False, True])
data = np.array(data)[:,condition]
```

output:

```
[4.  4. ]
 [6.6 9.5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list, do:

```
import numpy as np

data = [np.array([4,2,3,4], dtype=np.uint16),
        np.array([6.6, 7.4, 5.0, 9.5], dtype=np.float32)]

condition = np.array([True, False, False, True])


result = [e[condition] for e in data]
print(result)
```